# Structure of BDD tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm digging into Capybara and rspec, to move from TDD to BDD.

My generators make a whole lot of directories and spec tests,

with directory structure similar to this:

```
     spec
        controllers
        models
        requests
        routing
        views
```

I think that most of this is TDD rather than BDD. If I read [here](https://github.com/afshinator/OdinRailsStudyGroup/blob/master/week6-transcript.md):

> "A great testing strategy is to extensively cover the data layer with
>   unit tests then skip all the way up to acceptance tests. This approach
>   gives great code coverage and builds a test suite that can flex with a
>   changing codebase."

Then I figure that things should be quite different

something on the lines of:

```
     spec
         models
         acceptance
```

Basically I take out controllers, requests, views, and routing to just implement tests as user case scenarios in the acceptance directory with Capybara, Rspec.

This makes sense to me, though I'm not sure if this is the standard/common approach to this.

What is your approach?

Thanks, 
Giulio

Comment: I'm finding capybara tests to be quite slow right now, so moving to controller tests as much as possible: render a view, see if some appropriate HTML/text shows up. Trying to use jasmine for front-end, javascript testing. So controller tests for "smoke tests", unit tests for models, jasmine for the JS, capybara when we have to.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by slow? is that in terms of the time it takes for them to execute?

Comment: Yes, slow in terms of time to execute.

Comment: Yes, capybara tests are quite slow compared to basic tests.

Comment: With capybara rspec combo, tests typically go in a 'feature' directory - http://blog.liveeditorcms.com/introduction-feature-specs-rspec/

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr 
This is not a standard approach.

If you only test models and feature specs... then you miss out on the bits in the middle.

You can tell: "method X broke on the Widget model" or you can tell "there's *something* wrong while creating widgets" but you have no knowledge of anything else.

If something broke, was it the controller? the routing? some hand-over between the two?

it's good to have:

1. extremely thorough testing at the model-level (eg check every validation, every method, every option based on incoming arguments)
2. rough testing in the middle to make sure sub-systems work the way you expect (eg controllers set up the right variables and call the right templates/redirections given a certain set of circumstances)
3. overall feature testing as smoke-tests (eg that a user can go through the happy path and everything works the way they expect... that if they input bad stuff, that the app is throwing up the right error messages and redisplaying the forms for them to fix the problem)

Don't forget that models aren't the only classes in your app.. and all classes need some kind of testing. Controllers are classes too. As are form and service objects, mailers, etc.

That said - it's common to consider that view-tests are going overboard. I'm also not keen on request-tests our routing test myself (unless I have something complex which I want to work right, eg lots of optional params in a route that map to interesting search-patterns)